# Django suppresses exception in production mode

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a code that causes an exception (function called from template).

When `DEBUG=True` it correctly raises Exception.

But when `DEBUG=False` just blank page is displayed.

What should I do to disable such behavior?

Comment: You should define custom 500 server error page to inform user that something went wrong. [More info](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to show the Django debugging exception page in production, you **shouldn't** do this.

If you just want to create a custom error page, create a template called `500.html` - this will be rendered instead of a blank page.

Comment: Already added 500 page. Sometimes there is just blank template instead of error.

Comment: Sometimes? Are you sure a Django 500 error is even occurring?

Comment: Yes, KeyError occurs. In development mode I see error.